# itemize not working in beamer class

Tags: beamer, itemize, enumitem, pgfgantt

I have multiple itemizes present in my work. So I am trying to change the itemization of the Gantt chart. I am unable to make the necessary changes.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[top=.8in, bottom=.8in, left=.8in, right=.8in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfgantt}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{}
\resizebox{0.94\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance=0cm]
%\node[align=center] at (0,0) (o){};% {This is\\ adjust node};
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=.6cm,
y unit chart=1cm,
%vgrid={*6{white}, *1{black,dashed,thick}, *2{white}, *{1}{black,thick}, *8{white}}
vgrid={*{2}{lightgray},*{1}{black!60},*{2}{lightgray},*{1}{black!80}},
hgrid={lightgray},
today=18.25,
    today rule/.style={
        draw=blue,
        dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
        line width=1.5pt
    },
%newline shortcut=true,
%bar label anchor/.append style={align=right, text width=8em},
bar label node/.append style={align=left, text width=6cm},
bar label node/.append style={anchor=east},
%title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=0,
title right shift=0,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!80},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=.4%,
%group right shift=0,
%group top shift=.6,
%group height=.3
]{1}{30}
%   \gantttitle{Time Period}{36} \\
    \gantttitle{1234--0011}{6}
    \gantttitle{1124--0011}{6}
    \gantttitle{1141--0011}{6}
    \gantttitle{4121--2065}{6}
    \gantttitle{122--223}{6}\\
    \gantttitle{A}{3}
    \gantttitle{S}{3}
    \gantttitle{V}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q}{3}
    \gantttitle{T}{3}
    \gantttitle{M}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q}{3}
    \gantttitle{H}{3}
    \gantttitle{W}{3}
    \gantttitle{B}{3}\\
%%  \gantttitlelist{}{1}\\
%%  \gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
%%  \gantttitlelist{"J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D",
%%  "J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D",
%%  "J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D"}{1}\\

    \ganttbar[name=b1]{\small\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[1.] Testing\hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{.5em}{$\cdots$}}\end{itemize}}{1}{6} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b2]{\small\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[2.]  Survey \hfill \textcolor{gray}{$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$}\end{itemize}}{3}{10} \ganttnewline
    
    \ganttbar[name=b3]{\small\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[3.] Analyzing \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots$}}\end{itemize}}{4}{12} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b4]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[4.] Extraction of sentiments (Obj\#2)\hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{.5em}{}} \end{itemize}}{8}{17} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b5]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[5.] Tackling \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{12}{20} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b6]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[6.] Characterization \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{15}{22} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b7]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[7.] Effect \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{16}{26} \ganttnewline
    
    \ganttbar[name=b8]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[8.] Compilation \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{27}{30} %\ganttnewline
%
%   \ganttbar[name=b9]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[9.] Semantic Module Design \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{20}{27} \ganttnewline
%
%   \ganttbar[name=b10]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[10.] Semantic Fusion and Re-Identification \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{.5em}{$\cdots\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{27}{33} \ganttnewline
%
%   \ganttbar[name=b11]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[11.] Report Preparation\hfill \textcolor{gray}{{$\cdots\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{34}{36}    
\end{ganttchart}

%\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (b1) {}; %This line is for demo
%\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt] at (o) {};
%    \draw[dashed] (o) |- (b1); % This too!
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{block}{}
        
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Explored 
            \item  current 
            \item It a
            \item Innovating 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Don't use the `enumitem` package with beamer, they are not compatible
- beamer already loads the `geometry` package for you. You can't load it a second time with conflicting options
- beamer already loads the `xcolor` package, not necessary to load it again
- you are missing the `frame` environment. This is a most crutial part for beamer to set up its page elements. Don't place any text outside of frame environments
- instead of using `\thispagestyle{empty}` I suggest to use a `plain` frame
- instead of manually doing the numeration and formatting of your items, it would be easier to let latex do this for you
- if you still feel the urge to adjust the spacing in your lists, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72557572/2777074 how to do this without using incompatible packages

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}
\geometry{top=.8in, bottom=.8in, left=.8in, right=.8in,landscape}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfgantt}
%\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{0}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\refstepcounter{foo}\small\structure{\thefoo.} \parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{#1\dotfill}\color{gray}}

\begin{document}
\section*{}

\begin{frame}[plain]
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\resizebox{0.94\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance=0cm]
%\node[align=center] at (0,0) (o){};% {This is\\ adjust node};
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=.6cm,
y unit chart=1cm,
%vgrid={*6{white}, *1{black,dashed,thick}, *2{white}, *{1}{black,thick}, *8{white}}
vgrid={*{2}{lightgray},*{1}{black!60},*{2}{lightgray},*{1}{black!80}},
hgrid={lightgray},
today=18.25,
    today rule/.style={
        draw=blue,
        dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
        line width=1.5pt
    },
%newline shortcut=true,
%bar label anchor/.append style={align=right, text width=8em},
bar label node/.append style={align=left, text width=6cm},
bar label node/.append style={anchor=east},
%title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=0,
title right shift=0,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!80},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=.4%,
%group right shift=0,
%group top shift=.6,
%group height=.3
]{1}{30}
%   \gantttitle{Time Period}{36} \\
    \gantttitle{1234--0011}{6}
    \gantttitle{1124--0011}{6}
    \gantttitle{1141--0011}{6}
    \gantttitle{4121--2065}{6}
    \gantttitle{122--223}{6}\\
    \gantttitle{A}{3}
    \gantttitle{S}{3}
    \gantttitle{V}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q}{3}
    \gantttitle{T}{3}
    \gantttitle{M}{3}
    \gantttitle{Q}{3}
    \gantttitle{H}{3}
    \gantttitle{W}{3}
    \gantttitle{B}{3}\\
%%  \gantttitlelist{}{1}\\
%%  \gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
%%  \gantttitlelist{"J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D",
%%  "J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D",
%%  "J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D"}{1}\\

    \ganttbar[name=b1]{\myitem{Testing}}{1}{6} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b2]{\myitem{Survey}}{3}{10} \ganttnewline
    
    \ganttbar[name=b3]{\myitem{Analyzing}}{4}{12} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b4]{\myitem{Extraction of sentiments (Obj\#2) long sentance with more than one line}}{8}{17} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b5]{\myitem{Tackling}}{12}{20} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b6]{\myitem{Characterization}}{15}{22} \ganttnewline

    \ganttbar[name=b7]{\myitem{Effect}}{16}{26} \ganttnewline
    
    \ganttbar[name=b8]{\myitem{Compilation}}{27}{30} %\ganttnewline
%
%   \ganttbar[name=b9]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[9.] Semantic Module Design \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{0em}{$\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{20}{27} \ganttnewline
%
%   \ganttbar[name=b10]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[10.] Semantic Fusion and Re-Identification \hfill \textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{.5em}{$\cdots\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{27}{33} \ganttnewline
%
%   \ganttbar[name=b11]{\footnotesize\setlist{nolistsep}\vspace{-1.5em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]\item[11.] Report Preparation\hfill \textcolor{gray}{{$\cdots\cdots\cdots$}} \end{itemize}}{34}{36}    
\end{ganttchart}

%\node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (b1) {}; %This line is for demo
%\node[fill,circle,inner sep=3pt] at (o) {};
%    \draw[dashed] (o) |- (b1); % This too!
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{block}{}
        
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Explored 
            \item  current 
            \item It a
            \item Innovating 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the indentation is missing when the sentence is of more than one line. Can you please help?

Comment: @avi007 Like this? `\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\refstepcounter{foo}\small\structure{\thefoo.} \parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{#1\dotfill}\color{gray}}` If this does not solve your problem, please do ask a new question including a minimal working example that shows the problem